# How to query data range including data formatting (color, font) in Google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

How to modify this formula to make the result get the data with its original color & font formatting.

`=query(Sheet1!A1:D,"select A,B,C,D where A is not null",0)`

Lets say I want only column D to be in the new tab with its original color format.

Answer (score 0):

That cannot be done with `query()` or any other Google Sheets built-in function, so you will have to write your own custom code in Google Apps Script.

Some of the best resources for learning Google Apps Script include the [Beginner's Guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-beginner-guide/), the [New Apps Script Editor guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-ide/), the [Fundamentals of Apps Script with Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-1) codelab, the [Extending Google Sheets page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets), [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/), [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) and [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).

Comment: Your answer will be more helpful if you suggest a workaround or alternative.